# UI not reactive / doesn't rerender after state update

Tags: vue.js, vuex, vuetify.js

I built the following simple UI.

[image: screenshot of UI]

On clicking the trash icon, the bookmark should be deleted and the UI updated, because of the state change. The API call is made, and I can see in the dev tools, that the action takes place. However, I have to either merge the action or navigate away from the page or do a hard reload for the deleted bookmark not to show up. I expected this to work through the usage of vuex's mapState helper.

Below are the relevant parts.

view (sorry, this is a little messy) - this is actually the unabridged version:

```
<template>
  <div>
    <v-card class="mx-auto" max-width="700">
      <v-list two-line subheader>
        <v-subheader>Bookmarks</v-subheader>
        <v-list-item
          v-for="obj in Object.entries(bookmarks).sort((a, b) => {
            return a[1].paragraph - b[1].paragraph;
          })"
          :key="obj[0]"
        >
          <v-list-item-avatar>
            <v-icon @click="goTo(obj)">mdi-bookmark</v-icon>
          </v-list-item-avatar>
          <v-list-item-content @click="goTo(obj)">
            <v-list-item-title>
              {{ obj[0].split('/')[1] + ' by ' + obj[0].split('/')[0] }}
            </v-list-item-title>
            <v-list-item-subtitle>
              Part {{ obj[1].part + 1 }}, paragraph {{ obj[1].paragraph + 1 }}
            </v-list-item-subtitle>
          </v-list-item-content>
          <v-list-item-action>
            <v-btn icon>
              <v-icon @click="deleteBookmark(obj[0])" title="Remove bookmark"
                >mdi-delete</v-icon
              >
            </v-btn>
          </v-list-item-action>
        </v-list-item>
      </v-list>
    </v-card>
  </div>
</template>
<script>
import { mapState, mapActions } from 'vuex';
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState(['bookmarks'])
  },
  methods: {
    ...mapActions(['deleteBookmark']),
    goTo(obj) {
      const [authorName, title] = obj[0].split('/');
      this.$router.push({
        name: 'showText',
        params: {
          authorName,
          title
        },
        query: { part: obj[1].part, paragraph: obj[1].paragraph }
      });
    }
  }
};
</script>
```

store:

```
import Vue from 'vue';
import Vuex from 'vuex';

Vue.use(Vuex);

import apiService from '@/services/ApiService';

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    bookmarks: {}
  },
  mutations: {
    SET_BOOKMARKS(state, bookmarks) {
      state.bookmarks = bookmarks;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    async deleteBookmark({ commit, state }, key) {
      let { bookmarks } = state;
      const response = await apiService.deleteBookmark(key);
      delete bookmarks[key];
      commit('SET_BOOKMARKS', bookmarks);
      return response;
    }
  }
});

export default store;
```

apiService:

```
import axios from 'axios';

const apiClient = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  withCredentials: true,
  headers: {
    Accept: 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
  },
  responseType: 'json'
});

export default {
  deleteBookmark(key) {
    return apiClient.delete(`/api/bookmarks/${key}`);
  }
};
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Red flag right here:

```js
delete bookmarks[key];
```

Please read [Change Detection Caveats](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html#For-Objects).

Use [`Vue.delete`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#Vue-delete) instead:

```js
Vue.delete(bookmarks, key);
```

Doing `commit('SET_BOOKMARKS', bookmarks);` immediately after doesn't result in any change happening because you're just assigning the same object instance. It might be best to write a `REMOVE_BOOKMARK` mutation to handle this so you're not changing the Vuex state outside of a mutation.

Comment: I was assuming that deleting the key / value pair from the object and reassigning that mutated object to `state.bookmarks` would be considered a change that vuex detects. Am I wrong?

Comment: It doesn't work like that. When you delete a property from the object, it's still the same object instance. When you reassign to `state.bookmarks`, Vue essentially does `newValue === oldValue` and so it sees that the object instance is the same so it doesn't trigger an update.